# Create a Word document from a template file c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openxml

I am trying to  make a word document in an asp.Net MVC application using OpenXML template document .
The main challenges for me are

1. How can i create a word document as an OpenXML template? In my word
   document i have some paragraphs of texts and in every paragraphs i
   have to fill information from data base like in word file there are
   instances of text like   
    etc and these should be filled with actual data. But
   i dont know how can i convert a normal word document as a OpenXML
   template file .
2. How can i fill the values with data from db ? If i have a model say WordModel in hand with filled values of properties FirstName TotalAmount AmountUnit TotalCopies etc then how can i fill the details to template and allow user to download the file ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called Mail Merge and means populating word documents that act as templates with your application data. There are some existing (commercial) solutions out there, but if you want to do it yourself using Open XML SDK, you need to set up some kind of tagging mechanism that you will use to tag certain parts of document where you want the data/text from the database should be placed. For Word documents you have the following options: Bookmarks, Content Controls, Merge Fields, or special text (<% FirstName %>). I would personally go with Content Controls as they offer the best user experience and they are pretty easy to parse and replace. So the templates would be ordinary word documents containing these tags and then you could use Open XML SDK to parse these templates, search the tags in them and replace them with your application data according to the tag's name/code/title. This a very abstract, high level picture of a mail merge processor. Of course system like this is not easy to implement and also note that using Open XML requires some learning. There was a similar [question answered](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/742234/How-to-create-a-Word-document-from-data-values), but you can probably find many more - just google.